# What would cause a theme to add extra characters to blog post links?

Tags: permalinks, themes, 404-error

I've been working for the past couple days to figure out why a theme is adding " title=" to the end of a given blog post's URL, resulting in a 404 error.

I've authored test posts, same result.

I've examined the header, footer, single, index, & functions files & have run through all of the plugins but I've been wildly unsuccessful at locating the issue.

Any insight is appreciated - I feel like the issue is in the theme somewhere & it's telling WP to do something in relation to the post's permalink that isn't being accurately translated but I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you taken the basic debugging steps? Try switching to a standard theme, and see if the issue perseveres. If not, turn off all plugins, and check again.

Comment: what theme? where did you download it from?

Comment: Hey guys - it's a custom theme we developed for a customer & all was working fine previously.  I'm the admin guy & am a WP n00b, learning as I go.  

I did use the theme checker plugin & checked the debug log but I'm not seeing anything that should be triggering this.

Comment: RESOLVED
I checked again & found a missing quotation mark in the entry file.